# Why is my brute force substring search returning extra counts?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

Doing some work with timing different algorithms, however my brute force implementation which I have found numerous times on different sites is sometimes returning more results than, say, Notepad++ search or VSCode search. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The program opens a txt file with a DNA strand string of length 10000000 and searches and counts the number of occurrences of the string passed in via command line.

Algorithm:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // read in dna strand
    ifstream file("dna.txt");
    string dna((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    dna.c_str();
    int dnaLength = dna.length();
    cout << "DNA Strand Length: " << dnaLength << endl;
    string pat = argv[1];
    cout << "Pattern: " << pat << endl;

    // algorithm
    int M = pat.length();
    int N = dnaLength;
    int localCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            if (dna.at(i + j) != pat.at(j)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == M) {
            localCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ***The program opens a txt file with a DNA strand string of length 10000000 and searches and counts the number of occurrences*** My advice is to start with a smaller dataset where you know and can easily find the answer so you can debug your code in a debugger.

Comment: Did you try the function std::string::find(const string& pat, size_t position) ?
 In your case, it will become:  int count=0; int pos=dna.find(pat);  while( pos != std::string::npos) { ++count; pos = dna.find(pat, pos + M); }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference might be because your algorithm also counts overlapping results, while a quick check with Notepad++ shows that it does not.
Example:

Let dna be "FooFooFooFoo"

And your pattern "FooFoo"

What result do you expect? Notepad++ shows 2 (one starts at position 1, the second at position 7 (after the first).

Your algorithm will find 3 (position 1, 4 and 7)

Comment: Yes this is the reason. Thank you. I need to walk through and figure out how to fix that. Although, I may actually think that it's better to have the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

In your algorithm, the index i increase by 1 every loop. This may cause double counting for some searching pattern. For eaxample, search for ABAB in the text ... ABABABABABAB .... The answer may be 5 times in your methods, and it would be 3 times if each character is not allowed to be double counted. Which answer you want?

To avoid double counting, you may rewrite the index i to a while loop:

```
i = 0;
while (i < M)
{
   for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if (dna.at(i + j) != pat.at(j)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j == M) {
        localCount++;
        i += M;
      }
    else ++i;
}
```

Or, you can employ the function std::string::find(const string&, int p=0). The first argument is the pattern to look for, and the second the position to start search:

```
  int pos = 0, count=0;
  pos = dna.find(pat);   // initial serach start from pos=0;
  while( pos != std::string::npos) {   // while not end of string
     ++count;
     pos = dna.find(pat, pos + M); // start search from pos+M
    }
```

These two methods provide a self-confirmation for confidence.